# want to write event from event hub to Data Lake store using C# without stream analytics

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-data-lake

want to write event from event hub to Data Lake store using C# without stream analytics.

we are able to write in BLOB but how we can write in data lake.

Comment: copy from blob to data lake or you could use data factory as well . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995314/how-to-copy-azure-blob-files-to-azure-data-lake-analyticis

Answer (score 0):

Other than Azure Stream Analytics, there are few other options you could use. We have listed them at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-scenarios - search for "Streamed data".

Do these meet your requirements?

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager,
Azure Data Lake.

Answer (score 0):

You can try connecting the eventhub triggered function to blob storage as an output binding and then orchestrate a movement of data from blob to data lake.
This way we can save some efforts and process the datas in batch as well.
Considering other options such as Azure functions to Data Lake which involves complex operation such as appending the events in same file till a threshold and then flushing to data lake,it might not be ideal for real time environment.